# Look-and-Say sequence: How dependent on English?

Tags: sequences-and-series

To what extent is Conway's [Look-and-Say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) sequence
dependent on English?
Are there languages in which the sequence is not
the same as 
$$
1,11,21,1211,111221,312211,13112221, \ldots \;\;?
$$
I am worried that, e.g., in English, $21$ is twenty-one, $20+1$ while in German, $21$ is ein­-und­-zwanzig, $1+20$. Maybe we are protected in that the Look-and-Say sequence never approaches such numbers, but the possibility exists, doesn't it?

Comment: I don’t see how it could depend on the language, unless it’s a language that cannot name all numbers (like Piraha); but then the sequence is not well defined, rather than different. Note that you are only counting and naming the numerals, so the language you use to count and name do not change the numbers.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Tried to make my worry more explicit...

Comment: I don’t think that’s how the “Look and Say” sequence is defined. if you see twenty one x’s, then that part of the sequence would be “21x”, regardless of whether you say “twenty and one” or you say “one and twenty”. You first write down the numeral for the amount of x’s that you see, then you write down the numeral x. In french, if you had eighty consecutive 3s you would not write “4203” (four twenty three, since eighty is “quatre vingt”), you would still write “803”.

Comment: In English, the numeral adjective *precedes* the  noun referring to a symbol in the sequence.  In some languages—and even occasionally in English—adjectives can *follow* the nouns they qualify.  I've no idea whether there's a language in which numeral adjectives normally follow the nouns they qualify, but if there is, the *Look and Say* sequence would be $$ 1, 11, 12, 1121, 122111, 112213, 12221131, …\ ,$$that is, with the digits of each term of the sequence in reverse order from what they are in English.

Comment: I know a linguist. I can ask and see if they know any such languages, @lonzaleggiera.

Comment: So, it appears that it is possible that in Japanese one would first say the numeral and then the quantity. I'm trying to confirm. If so, I will post the answer...

Comment: In Hebrew you say the counting number before the object you're counting EXCEPT when it is 1, so you say "flower one"(פרח אחד) instead of "one flower", so the sequence would look like this:
$$1,11,21,2111, 2131,21113111,21313131,21113111311131113111,2131313131313131313,\dots$$